# When I render a small circle using JavaScript's getContext("2d"), it renders with a piece missing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a very simple interactive segment for a webpage, and I need to render many small circles that bounce around the screen... However I am running into a very strange issue. When I render a small circle (with a radius of ~10 or less) it renders with a chunk taken out of the upper right corner for no apparent reason. If I increase the size of the circle then it begins to render properly.

Here is all of my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Nothing</title>
        <style>
            #header{
                background: red;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 25%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #header h1{
                position: relative;
                top: 8%;
                font-size: 200%;
            }
            #header canvas{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <canvas></canvas>
            <h1>(Removed for privacy)</h1>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            let canvas = document.getElementById("header").getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
            canvas.width = Math.round(window.innerWidth);
            canvas.height = Math.round(window.innerHeight * 0.25);
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            let width = canvas.width;
            let height = canvas.height;
            
            function d2r(degrees){
                return(degrees * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            
            function random(min,max){
                const diff = (max - min) + 1;
                return(Math.floor(Math.random() * diff) + min);
            }
        </script>
        
        <script>
            class Bubble{
                constructor(x,y){
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                    this.r = random(0,d2r(360));
                    this.speed = 0.6;
                    this.xvel = Math.cos(this.r) * this.speed;
                    this.yvel = Math.sin(this.r) * this.speed;
                    this.size = 10;
                }
                draw(){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size / 2,this.size / 2,0,d2r(360));
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                update(){
                    this.x += this.xvel;
                    this.y += this.yvel;
                    if(this.x < this.size / 2){
                        this.x = this.size / 2;
                        this.xvel = -this.xvel;
                    }
                    if(this.x > width - this.size / 2){
                        this.x = width - this.size / 2;
                        this.xvel = -this.xvel;
                    }
                    if(this.y < this.size / 2){
                        this.y = this.size / 2;
                        this.yvel = -this.yvel;
                    }
                    if(this.y > height - this.size / 2){
                        this.y = height - this.size / 2;
                        this.yvel = -this.yvel;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            let bubbles = [];
            
            for(let i = 0;i < 50;i++){
                bubbles.push(new Bubble(random(4,width - 4),random(4,height - 4)));
            }
        </script>
        
        <script>
            let drawLoop = setInterval(function(){
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(84, 48, 23)";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
                for(let i = 0;i < bubbles.length;i++){
                    bubbles[i].update();
                    bubbles[i].draw();
                }
            },1000 / 60);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can change the `this.size = 10;` to different sizes to see how it looks, and when the problem comes and goes. When I set it to something tiny (like 5) it renders as almost a line.... It's very very strange.

Any help is appreciated. I assume I'm going to have to use some kind of workaround to get this working the way I want.

Edit: The code in question is in the `Bubble` class, inside the `draw` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters for 2dArc is

```
void ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle [, anticlockwise]);
```

Inside your class member draw() you gave,

```
ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size / 2,this.size / 2,0,d2r(360));
```

Among which the second **this.size / 2** is not required,

removing that will fix it,

```
ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size / 2,0,d2r(360));
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. Wow, thank you so much. I feel so stupid now. I've spent the last 5 years of my life working exclusively with `ellipse()` drawing commands, and my brain has trained myself to naturally provide both a width and a height. This is my first time working with JavaScript's canvas context and I totally overlooked that somehow. Thank you very much for your answer. I spent like 30 minutes looking into this and I can't believe I didn't catch that, lol.